# How do I order nodes in graphviz when using edges doesn't work?

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to create a flow control graph in graphviz, but I can't get the nodes to stay in the order. I tried prefixing them with a number as that is the only way I could get clusters to go in the right order (by trial an error), but this doesn't work for nodes.

I gave a weight of 100 to the nodes for ordering (which I intend to make invisible once they actually WORK) to no avail.

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR;
splines=ortho;
subgraph cluster_I {
    color=lightgrey;
    style=filled;
    label="Incoming Numbers";
    newrank="true";
    node [color=white, 
          style=filled];
    "thisExtention" [color=lightskyblue1, 
                     shape=square, 
                     style="rounded, filled", 
                     label="Extension 20"];
    "+15412362468" [color=azure, 
                    shape=rectangle, 
                    style="rounded, filled"];
    "+15412362468" -> "thisExtention"  [tailport=e];
    "+12069732753" [color=azure, 
                    shape=rectangle, 
                    style="rounded, filled"];
    "+12069732753" -> "thisExtention"  [tailport=e];
    "+441134037186" [color=azure, 
                     shape=rectangle, 
                     style="rounded, filled"];
    "+441134037186" -> "thisExtention"  [tailport=e];
    {
        rank=same;
        "+15412362468";
        "+12069732753";
        "+441134037186";
    }
}
subgraph cluster_A {
    color=blue;
    subgraph cluster_1W {
        color=lightgrey;
        style=filled;
        "actionstart" [label="Start Inbound Action Steps\n(can be interrupted by menu dial)"];
        "thisExtention" -> "actionstart"  [tailport=e];
    }
    subgraph cluster_2G {
        color=aquamarine2;
        style=filled;
        "2if" [color=azure, 
               shape=diamond, 
               label="IF MENUKEY does equal 4"];
        "3if" [color=azure, 
               shape=diamond, 
               label="IF SUM does equal 2\nAND INSIDE “BUSINESS HOURS”"];
        "4ring" [color=azure, 
                 shape=rectangle, 
                 label="ring"];
        "6playrecording" [color=azure, 
                          shape=rectangle, 
                          label="playrecording"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_3Y {
        color=salmon1;
        style=filled;
        "7else" [color=azure, 
                 shape=diamond, 
                 label=ELSE];
        "8playrecording" [color=azure, 
                          shape=rectangle, 
                          label="playrecording"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_W4 {
        color=lightgrey;
        style=filled;
        "9transfer" [color=azure, 
                     shape=rectangle, 
                     label="transfer"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_5G {
        color=aquamarine2;
        style=filled;
        "10else" [color=azure, 
                  shape=diamond, 
                  label=ELSE];
        "11hangup" [color=azure, 
                    shape=rectangle, 
                    label="hangup"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_O {
        color=lightgray;
        style=filled;
        label="Dial Menu";
        "17ring" [color=azure, 
                  shape=rectangle, 
                  label="DIAL (#):\nring"];
        "18set" [color=azure, 
                 shape=rectangle, 
                 label="DIAL ①:\nset"];
        "19playrecording" [color=azure, 
                           shape=rectangle, 
                           label="DIAL ②:\nplayrecording"];
        "20huntgroup" [color=azure, 
                       shape=rectangle, 
                       label="DIAL ③:\nRing HuntGroup: test hunt group"];
        "21transfer" [color=azure, 
                      shape=rectangle, 
                      label="DIAL ④:\ntransfer"];
        "22huntgroup" [color=azure, 
                       shape=rectangle, 
                       label="DIAL ⑤:\nRing HuntGroup: test hunt group"];
    }
    {
        rank="same";
        "actionstart";
        "2if";
        "3if";
        "4ring";
        "6playrecording";
        "7else";
        "8playrecording";
        "9transfer";
        "10else";
        "11hangup";
        "17ring";
        "18set";
        "19playrecording";
        "20huntgroup";
        "21transfer";
        "22huntgroup";
    }
    "actionstart" -> "2if"  [weight=100];
    "2if" -> "3if"  [weight=100];
    "3if" -> "4ring"  [weight=100];
    "4ring" -> "6playrecording"  [weight=100];
    "6playrecording" -> "7else"  [weight=100];
    "7else" -> "8playrecording"  [weight=100];
    "8playrecording" -> "9transfer"  [weight=100];
    "9transfer" -> "10else"  [weight=100];
    "10else" -> "11hangup"  [weight=100];
    "11hangup" -> "17ring"  [weight=100];
    "17ring" -> "18set"  [weight=100];
    "18set" -> "19playrecording"  [weight=100];
    "19playrecording" -> "20huntgroup"  [weight=100];
    "20huntgroup" -> "21transfer"  [weight=100];
    "21transfer" -> "22huntgroup"  [weight=100];
}
subgraph columnthree {
    "Extension 10" [shape=square, 
                    style="rounded, filled", 
                    fillcolor=lightskyblue1];
    "9transfer" -> "Extension 10"  [weight=0, 
                                    tailport=e];
    "HuntGroup 2" [shape=septagon, 
                   style="filled", 
                   fillcolor=lightcyan1];
    "20huntgroup" -> "HuntGroup 2"  [weight=0, 
                                     tailport=e];
    "Extension 10" [shape=square, 
                    style="rounded, filled", 
                    fillcolor=lightskyblue1];
    "21transfer" -> "Extension 10"  [weight=0, 
                                     tailport=e];
    "HuntGroup 2" [shape=septagon, 
                   style="filled", 
                   fillcolor=lightcyan1];
    "22huntgroup" -> "HuntGroup 2"  [weight=0, 
                                     tailport=e];
    }
}
```

[image: click here for image]

Comment: I'm also open to any suggestions for a better library to use to generate the SVG file. graphviz doesn't seem to be well suited for this due to it's lack of ordering ability.

Comment: you should probably use `rankdir=TB` as this is your principal ordering.